# Ionic 2: APK output corrupted on android device

Tags: android, bash, ionic2, apk

I have developed an app with Ionic 2 and would like to test it on an Android phone. Thus in my bash CLI, I tried to run several commands to build the APK, such as:

```
ionic cordova build android --release
ionic cordova build --release android
ionic cordova build android --release --prod
ionic cordova build android --prod
```

In the end, the APK file is generated, but when I transfer it on my android phone, it says the app is corrupted and it won't run.
Any ideas how to fix my problem? Thanks.

EDIT: I also tried to plug my phone by USB. `adb devices` returns a list showing that my device is indeed connected. Then I ran `ionic cordova run android`, but I get an error : `Your Android platform does not have api.js`.

`ionic info` output:

```
global packages:

    @ionic/cli-utils : 1.4.0
    Cordova CLI      : 7.0.0
    Ionic CLI        : 3.4.0

local packages:

    @ionic/app-scripts              : 1.3.7
    @ionic/cli-plugin-cordova       : 1.4.0
    @ionic/cli-plugin-ionic-angular : 1.3.1
    Cordova Platforms               : browser broken ios 4.4.0
    Ionic Framework                 : ionic-angular 3.1.1

System:

    Node       : v6.10.3
    OS         : Windows 10
    Xcode      : not installed
    ios-deploy : not installed
    ios-sim    : not installed
    npm        : 3.10.10
```

Comment: Have tried installing on other device? Does ionic cordova run android is working?

Comment: I believe the problem doesn't come from the phone, because I used to be able to run on this device an app we developed. `ionic cordova run android` doesn't work, it stops compiling after the `Your Android platform does not have api.js` error.

Comment: post output of `ionic info`.

Comment: Okay, I edited my question.

Answer (score 3):

I was facing the same issue, after a long R&D, I found the issue. As per my understanding, the issue is not with the Android build, its the generated unsigned APK that you are running on your mobile device. The fact is that system will not allow to install an application with unsigned instead, it will show the corrupt message. So whether you want to upload your application to Google Store or not you have to make the application signed so that the system will at least allow the application to install into the mobile device.

Kindly refer below step to generate signed APK

**Step 1**: Open command prompt and go to the JDK path's bin folder

**Step 2**: Now we need to create a new certificate/keystore to generate your private key using the keytool command that comes with the JDK.

> keytool -genkey -v -keystore my-release-key.jks -keyalg RSA -keysize
>   2048 -validity 10000 -alias my-alias

Or you can specify particular drive/folder where you want to generate keystore file

> keytool -genkey -v -keystore D:\my-release-key.jks -keyalg RSA
>   -keysize 2048 -validity 10000 -alias my-alias

You’ll first be prompted to create a password for the keystore. Then, answer the rest of the nice tools' questions and when it’s all done, you should have a file called my-release-key.jks created in the current or specified directory.

Note: Make sure to save this file somewhere safe, if you lose it you won’t be able to submit updates to your app!

**Step 3**: To sign the unsigned APK, run the jarsigner tool which is also included in the JDK:

> jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore
>   my-release-key.jks android-release-unsigned.apk my-alias

Or use below one, do forgot to specify the exact path to keystore.jks and app-release-unsigned.apk file

> jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -d igestalg SHA1 -keystore
>   D:\ionic_apk\my-release-key.jks
>   D:\Ionic...\platforms\android\app\build\outputs\apk\release\app-release-unsigned.apk
>   my-alias

That's it, you have just build a signed APK. Rename the APKfile if required. Copy that on your mobile device and install it.

So if you want to optimize you APK, then we need to run the zip align tool which can be found in /path/to/Android/sdk/build-tools/VERSION/zipalign. For example, on OS X with Android Studio installed, zipalign is in ~/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/VERSION/zipalign:

> zipalign -v 4 android-release-unsigned.apk HelloWorld.apk

To verify that your APK is signed run apksigner. The apksigner can be also found in the same path as the zipalign tool:

> apksigner verify HelloWorld.apk

Comment: Jarsigner is refusing to sign my apk (`jarsigner: unable to open jar file: android-release-unsigned.apk`).

I know where to look now though. Thank you. I'll come back here if I find a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Please use this guide: https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing#signapp

As @Prashob Thekkyal correctly have guessed, you have to signed the app before it can be installed by Android Nougat. That being said, `jarsigner` refuse to sign an `apk` file. You have to use the `apksigner` utility that is present in the android build-tools.

Answer (score 0):

`Cordova Platforms` should be  `android x.x.x` in your case.

Check `root/platforms/platform.json` it should be

```
 {
    "android": "x.x.x"
 }
```

Make sure your `android` folder is in right place(`root directory/platforms/android`).

Try removing and adding the platform again.